# Matching a substring of n numbers, but not if there are any numbers after that

Tags: regex

Basically I'm looking for a regex that matches some simple phone numbers.

I want to match numbers in a longer string of text like `123 4567`, `891-0111`, or `21314151`, something that is (hopefully) identified by `(\d{3,4}[- ]\d{3,4}|\d{4,8})`, but I don't want to match them if they're part of a longer number like `3919503570275`.

If I require the next character to be a non-digit or the end of a line, then that next character is also included in the match, which I don't want.

Comment: Are word  boundaries enough? `\b(?:\d{3,4}[- ]\d{3,4}|\d{4,8})\b`?

Comment: Yes. If I understand them correctly, they fit great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround your regex with a lookahead and a lookbehind to reject `\d` on both sides:

```
(?<!\d)(\d{3,4}[- ]\d{3,4}|\d{4,8})(?!\d)
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/I4t3EA/1)

Note that this would accept a string that looks like a phone number preceded or followed by letters.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what programming language you use, I suggest to either use negative look-ahead or to use groups to extract the number.

See https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for information about lookaround pattern.